# Apache URL resolution - serve html file as directory

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I've changed my web hosting provider and now I have a configuration problem:
In the root of my site, I have a file called `beta.html`. The Apache configuration on previous webhost would serve its content even if accessed as `http://example.com/beta` or `http://example.com/beta/`. The Apache on the new webhost treats those two cases as 404 error. Note that there is *no* directory named `beta` on that site.

Is there something I can do with `.htaccess` so that it serves the contents of beta.html without a client side redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `MultiViews` for the `Directory` in question.

```
<Directory /my/web/site>
    Options MultiViews # and your other options
</Directory>
```

Comment: Confirmed with previous hosting provider, this is what they had enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your old hosting provider had Aapche's [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) enabled, which allows Apache to correct minor case mismatches and/or spelling errors before displaying a 404 error.

Best practice is to leave it off, because it can cause quite a bit of overhead and doesn't discourage bad webdesign.

Comment: OK, is there something I can do? mod_rewrite?

Comment: You could try to enable mod_speling in your config, it's directives are even alllowed in .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to do this.  There are numerous tutorials on the web.

However I would caution that this is not a recommended practice due to conflicts, complexities, and SEO reasons.

For example see: [Rewrite .html file extensions with htaccess](https://www.alexscotton.com/post/rewrite-html-file-extensions-with-htaccess)
I've not tested this but have seen people use this and similar approaches.

Note that this will impact your entire site.  If you just want to do one URL, then add a `RewriteCond` so the filtering only applies to that URI.

```
# This tag ensures the rewrite module is loaded
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # enable the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On
  # Set your root directory
  RewriteBase /

  # remove the .html extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
  RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

  # remove index and reference the directory
  RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

  # remove trailing slash if not a directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

  # forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
</IfModule>
```